# How to get media source of text editor in WordPress

Tags: media, editor

I want to get source of files when I click add media. Suppose, when I select a pdf file I get

```
<a href="http://thedomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/myfile.pdf"rel="">myfile</a>
```

in text editor. Now I need to get value of "href" when I click the file from add media. Is there any built in WordPress function to get the value?

Comment: what have you tried? where is your research?. If there is a plugin, just read its code and get an inspiration from it

Comment: I have googled several times but I haven't get any satisfactory answer. By the way, I am new at plugin development. So it is very difficult for me to read and understand all the code inside a plugin. @Mark Kaplun

Comment: than you should ask specific questions about the things you do not understand. "design/implement a feature for me" (even if it was nice to ask such a thing for free) is just too broad for the format of the site

Comment: OK then, I am changing the last line of my question.